# How to Avoid Singular Matrix using R?

Tags: r, matrix, singular

I want to generate a nonsingular data matrix, and avoid the following error in R:

```
"Error in solve.default(sigma) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 1.3971e-16"
```

I am using the is.singular.matrix function in R. How to code the "discard x" part in the ifelse function?

```r
n=100
p=50
x<-0.5*matrix(rnorm(n*p),nrow=n,ncol=p)
ifelse(is.singular.matrix(x)=T, discard x, x=x)
```

Comment: what packages are you using?

Comment: Something doesn't make sense here. You are unlikely to get a singular matrix using `rnorm`. Moreover the matrix in your example is not square.

Comment: I am using the "matrixcalc" package.

Comment: `repeat{x<-0.5*matrix(rnorm(n*p),nrow=n,ncol=p); if(is.singular.matrix(x)){ break }}`.

Comment: A commonly used trick is to add a very small constant (e.g. `1e-9`) to the diagonal. However, it's hard to say if that's appropriate or the best approach for you without more context. Additionally, as @KarolisKoncevičius mentions, you're not even dealing with a square matrix in your example. Can you provide more context and a better [mcve]?